# Ошибка при компиляции проекта(с библиотекой Lombok) в Maven в IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, maven

При попытке скомпилировать проект в Maven (правая панель, пункт `compile`) вылазят ошибки:

```
/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk1.8.0_92/bin/java -Dmaven.home=/home/rostislav/IDEs/IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3 -Dclassworlds.conf=/home/rostislav/IDEs/IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/bin/m2.conf -Didea.launcher.port=7533 -Didea.launcher.bin.path=/home/rostislav/IDEs/IDEA/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/rostislav/IDEs/IDEA/plugins/maven/lib/maven3/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar:/home/rostislav/IDEs/IDEA/lib/idea_rt.jar com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2016.1.3 compile
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.dugin.rostislav:OSLoaderServer:jar:1.0
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 13, column 21
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OSLoaderServer 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ OSLoaderServer ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ OSLoaderServer ---
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 22 source files to /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[38,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[39,27] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[40,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[41,27] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[42,20] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[43,18] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageChanger.java:[20,13] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[78,45] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[123,96] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[153,58] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[154,65] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[155,58] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[169,88] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[164,86] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[165,86] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[195,86] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR]  variable image of type Image
/home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[196,92] error: cannot find symbol
[INFO] 17 errors 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.229s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Jul 29 02:04:36 MSK 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/137M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project OSLoaderServer: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[38,29] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[39,27] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[40,25] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[41,27] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[42,20] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/database/sqlite/ImageRecord.java:[43,18] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageChanger.java:[20,13] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[78,45] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[123,96] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[153,58] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[154,65] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[155,58] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[169,88] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[164,86] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[165,86] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[195,86] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] variable image of type Image
[ERROR] /home/rostislav/Projects/OSLoader/OSLoaderServer/src/main/java/com/dugin/rostislav/image/work/model/ImageCreater.java:[196,92] error: cannot find symbol
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

По факту, ошибки указывают на участки кода, где ошибок нет... Сборка через `Build` -> `Make Project` работает хорошо (если исключить то, что не подтягиваются зависимости).

---

Удалять `.m2` и перезапускать компиляцию пробовал - не помогло.

---

Как исправить эту ошибку и из-за чего она возникла?

---

**UPD_0:** класс `ImageRecord` (используется библиотека Lombok, которая создает геттеры и сеттеры, а так же ORM):

```
import com.dugin.rostislav.object.Image;
import com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField;
import com.j256.ormlite.misc.BaseDaoEnabled;
import com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

import static com.dugin.rostislav.image.ImagesConst.*;

@DatabaseTable(tableName = TABLE_NAME)
class ImageRecord extends BaseDaoEnabled {
    @Getter @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE_EMULATOR_TYPE)
    private Image.ImageEmulator imageEmulator;
    @Getter @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE_OS_TYPE)
    private Image.ImageOSType imageOSType;
    @Getter @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_IMAGE_TYPE)
    private Image.ImageType imageType;
    @Getter @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)
    private String description;
    @Getter @Setter
    @DatabaseField(columnName = COLUMN_NAME)
    private String name;
    @Getter @Setter
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private int id; //Auto generated DB column

    public ImageRecord() {
        //Void
    }

    ImageRecord(Image image) {
        imageEmulator = image.getImageEmulator();
        imageOSType = image.getImageOsType();
        imageType = image.getImageType();
        description = image.getDescription();
        name = image.getName();
        id = image.getId();
    }

    public Image toImage() {
        return Image.builder()
                .setImageType(imageType)
                .setImageEmulator(imageEmulator)
                .setImageOsType(imageOSType)
                .setDescription(description)
                .setName(name)
                .setId(id)
                .build();
    }
}
```

**UPD_1:** класс `Image`:

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

import java.io.Serializable;

@ToString
public class Image implements Serializable {
    public static class Builder implements Serializable {
        private ImageEmulator imageEmulator;
        private ImageOSType imageOsType;
        private ImageType imageType;
        private String name;
        private String path;
        private String description;
        private int id;

        private Builder() {
            //private constructor
        }

        public Builder setImageEmulator(ImageEmulator imageEmulator) {
            if (imageType == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Firstly, set image type");
            }

            if ((imageEmulator != null) && (imageType == ImageType.IMAGE_ISO)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Only OS and BIOS images has definite emulator");
            }

            this.imageEmulator = imageEmulator;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setImageOsType(ImageOSType imageOsType) {
            if (imageType == null) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Firstly, set image type");
            }

            if ((imageOsType != null) && (imageType != ImageType.IMAGE_OS)) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Only OS images has definite OS type");
            }

            this.imageOsType = imageOsType;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setImageType(ImageType imageType) {
            this.imageType = imageType;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setPath(String path) {
            this.path = path;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
            return this;
        }

        public Image build() {
            return new Image(this);
        }
    }

    public enum ImageType {IMAGE_OS, IMAGE_BIOS, IMAGE_ISO}
    public enum ImageEmulator {QEMU, BOCHS}
    public enum ImageOSType {WINDOWS, LINUX, OTHER}

    @Getter private ImageEmulator imageEmulator;
    @Getter private ImageOSType imageOsType;
    @Getter private ImageType imageType;
    @Getter private String name;
    @Getter private String path;
    @Getter private String description;
    @Getter @Setter private int id;

    private Image(Builder builder) {
        imageEmulator = builder.imageEmulator;
        imageOsType = builder.imageOsType;
        imageType = builder.imageType;
        name = builder.name;
        path = builder.path;
        description = builder.description;
        id = builder.id;
    }

    public static Builder builder() {
        return new Builder();
    }
}
```

---

**UPD_3:** фото из настроек IDEA:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: У вас в классе ImageCreater есть в разделе import  класс Image? Корректен импорт?

Comment: Нужно глянуть в класс ImageRecord.java укажите его исходный код в вопросе.

Comment: @Chubatiy, да, `import com.dugin.rostislav.object.Image;`.

Comment: @MikhailovValentine, добавил.

Comment: @MikhailovValentine, почему-то в конструкторе `ImageRecord(Image image)`, по мнению Maven, каждая строка усеянная ошибками.

Comment: @bukashka101 нужен класс com.dugin.rostislav.object.Image.

Comment: @MikhailovValentine, добавил.

Comment: imageEmulator = image.getImageEmulator() - геттера нет в Image. То же самое с остальными геттерами. Как и полей. Они у вас в билдере все

Comment: @Chubatiy, почему же? Все сеттеры в `Builder`, а геттеры и один сеттер в самом классе. Поля и геттеры расположены под классом `Builder`, если Вы не заметили.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Скорее всего проблема в библиотеке Lombok, которая не поддерживается в IntelliJ IDEA из коробки.
Нужно установить плагин и настроить поддержку аннотаций.

1. Устанавливаем плагин: Settings -> Plugins -> Search in repositories
   -> в поиске вводим Lombok.
2. После установки перезагружаем IntelliJ IDEA.
3. Включаем обработку аннотаций Lombok: Settings -> Build, Execution,
   Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors.

Теперь все должно компилироваться.

---

Также для некоторых версий IDE и maven нужно указать plugin в pom файле:

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <annotationProcessors>
                        <annotationProcessor>lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor
                        </annotationProcessor>
                    </annotationProcessors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Увы, но не помогло. И плагин, и обработка аннотаций были включены :((.

Comment: Странно я у себя отключаю обработку аннотаций точно такую ошибку получаю как у Вас - cannot find symbol.

Comment: Я добавил фото из настроек IDEA, может Вы заметите ошибку или еще что-то?

Comment: У меня после отключения тоже стала возникать ошибка победить смог только когда переключится на другую версию maven (в Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools ->Maven ->Maven home directoy) - apache-maven-3.3.3. Попробуйте!

Comment: @bukashka101, попробуйте еще добавить plugin в pom!

Comment: Ура! Помогло! Спасибо! :D

Comment: @bukashka101, пожалуйста!